# How to select all text and delete in vi?

Tags: vimscript, gvim, cut-copy-paste, insert-mode, edit

Is it possible to select all the text and delete it it in vi other than hitting backspace?

Comment: By pressing "`d`"?

Comment: if you want to delete it anyhow, just use `:%d`

Answer (score 3):

To delete text, use the `d` operator. This can be done from visual mode, but is normally done with a motion or text object, such as

- `daw` delete a word
- `d}` delete to end of paragraph
- `dd` delete a line

There is also a line-wise Ex command `:delete`. Coupled with the range `%` "all lines", `:%delete` deletes everything in a buffer.

Comment: I didn't know about `%delete`. Thanks for sharing this!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to empty the file with a simple mapping, then you can use:

```
nnoremap <Leader>g ggdG
```

This will map your leader key + `g` to execute the following:

- `gg` - Bounce to the first line in the file
- `dG` - This will delete the current line until the end of the file

Let me know if this answered your question!

Comment: To use D. Ben Knoble's [answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/39375/how-to-select-all-text-and-delete-in-vi/39387#39387), you can `map <Leader>g :%delete<CR>`.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I fixed up my answer. Thank you for your help!